# OpenCV-dnn make fails: 'calling a __device__ function("operator float") from a __host__ function("clipped_relu_eltwise_sum_2_inplace") is not allowed'

Tags: c, python-3.x, opencv, compiler-errors, gpu

I am following these instructions to build open-cv with GPU support:

https://techzizou.com/setup-opencv-dnn-cuda-module-for-linux/

My build command is

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/stepan/opencv \
    -D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_python3=ON \
    -D PYTHON3_LIBRARY=/home/stepan/anaconda3/envs/acne/lib \
    -D PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/stepan/anaconda3/envs/acne/include/python3.8 \
    -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=/home/stepan/anaconda3/envs/acne/bin/python3.8 \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D WITH_CUDA=ON \
    -D WITH_CUDNN=ON \
    -D OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON \
    -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 \
    -D CUDA_ARCH_BIN=6.1 \
    -D WITH_CUBLAS=1 \
    -D CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/cuda-10.2 \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/stepan/opencv_contrib/modules \
    -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc-6 \
    -D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=YES ..
```

The build sais nothing about `Python 3`. Previously it gave error messages about `Python 3.8.14 is not suitable: version 3.8.14 is required`. I've fixed this issue by installing a new Anaconda environment.

Now the build seem to work for `Python 3`. It does report errors for for `Python2.7`, even though I have a flag `-D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF \`
make -j command and make -j8 command fail with:

```
/home/sam/opencv/modules/dnn/src/cuda/activation_eltwise.cu(74): error: calling a __device__ function("operator float") from a __host__ function("clipped_relu_eltwise_sum_2_inplace") is not allowed
          detected during instantiation of "void cv::dnn::cuda4dnn::kernels::clipped_relu_eltwise_sum_2_inplace(const cv::dnn::cuda4dnn::csl::Stream &, cv::dnn::cuda4dnn::csl::Span<T>, cv::dnn::cuda4dnn::csl::View<T>, T, T) [with T=__half]"
(105): here

/home/sam/opencv/modules/dnn/src/cuda/activation_eltwise.cu(74): error: calling a __device__ function("operator float") from a __host__ function("clipped_relu_eltwise_sum_2_inplace") is not allowed
          detected during instantiation of "void cv::dnn::cuda4dnn::kernels::clipped_relu_eltwise_sum_2_inplace(const cv::dnn::cuda4dnn::csl::Stream &, cv::dnn::cuda4dnn::csl::Span<T>, cv::dnn::cuda4dnn::csl::View<T>, T, T) [with T=__half]"
(105): here

2 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00003924_00000000-4_activation_eltwise.cpp4.ii".
CMake Error at cuda_compile_1_generated_activation_eltwise.cu.o.RELEASE.cmake:281 (message):
  Error generating file
/home/sam/opencv/build/modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir/src/cuda/./cuda_compile_1_generated_activation_eltwise.cu.o
```

I am attaching the log of the build and of the make.

How to fix it?
build log: https://pastebin.com/DanW9YFS
make -j log: https://pastebin.com/Zgf2K64r
make -j8 log: https://pastebin.com/37TzJCxe

Comment: build issue with OpenCV and CUDA. I'd have recommended the cuda tag but some cuda regulars seem to hate these questions and remove the tag. it's also not C or Python. potentially your CUDA is too old, or too new (I doubt that).